# node.js - Sequelize querying tables

Tags: sequelize.js

I have these tables. Patients is connected to user and userAddress is connected to user.

[image]

I want to make a query in Sequelize where, given the Patient's Id I get the correct userAddress information. I can do it in two queries (first get the userId and then get the userAddress) but how do I do it in only one with Sequelize? From what I can see, the find method starts with one table and I can only include tables that are connected to that one. Am I missing something? How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this easily in sequelize, using the following query:

```
Patient.findAll({
  where: { id: 'ABC_123' },
  include: {
    model: User,
    include: [ UserAddress ]
  }
});
```

However, for the above query to work, your **Patient**, **User** and **UserAddress** models should be associated properly (i.e. in both directions), like so:

Between User and Patient:

```
Patient.belongsTo(models.User);
User.hasMany(models.Patient);
```

Between User and UserAddress:

```
UserAddress.belongsTo(models.User);
User.hasMany(models.UserAddress);
```

Comment: That way it would work, the problem is that I'm doing my thesis with a company and they have that schema that I can't change (they have a lot of tables in the schema with the same problem). Is this the only way?

Comment: Say, if you do not have association from User to UserAddress (User.hasMany(models.UserAddress)), then you'll not be able to include UserAddress in the query that I mentioned above (Sequelize will throw an exception, saying User is not associated with UserAddress).

However, if you cant change your model code,  you can still get around this using raw queries. See [this](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/) link